^ symbol in music theory
What does ^ above a number mean in music theory?
This notation seems to me to be a simple/elementary one. However I cannot find any direct answers to my question by looking it up. I assume, based on the context where I have  seen this being used, that it shows that the number which it is used on is a scale degree (which I need comfirmation on). An example of where I have most recently come across this symbol (this is a source's instruction on writing a major pentatonic scale):


Write a major scale, omitting 4^ and 7^. (The ^ symbol is supposed to be above the numbers, but I don't know if you can format it like
that.)
The resulting pattern will be: maj 2, maj 2, min 3, maj 2, min 3.


My guess is that the "4^" is the subdominant and the "7^" is the leading tone. Am I correct?
Additionally, is the ^ symbol still simply called a caret in the context of music theory, or is there a different name for it when used like this?

Whether you can format a ^ over numerals depends on the font and the rendering application.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928603/unicode-html-for-circumflex-over-numeral

The caret symbol above a number indicates a scale degree.  So, 3 with a caret above indicates the third scale degree, or the third note of the scale.
Relevant wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(music)
Relevant meta post about typing the notation in stackexchange (it does not work properly) : Displaying Scale Degrees

Surprisingly, in the Dolmetsch chart, the caret is only associated with dynamics, somewhere between sf and sfz. It's now been turned on its side (>) to mean the same.
However, on top, or in front of a number, its use is quite different. It signifies its number in the order of notes in a scale, as in tonic =^1, dominant =^5. Getting a little towards the NNS, which deals with chords, but representing single notes instead.
Interestingly, I've never seen it used with non-diatonics, such as ^♭5, but someone out there may prove me wrong.
